# SQL cursor some print are not being output

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, cursor

I have created a cursor in SQL. What I want is,

1. First get the Employee card no 6 months back of today's date  then,
2. Then I get the count of that employee
3. Then I calculate the the no of days worked and all by some calculation.

For that the cursor is something like below

```
IF(@Type = 'C') 
    BEGIN
            Print 'Yes I am in the Current process';        
        DECLARE daily_Allocate CURSOR FOR  
                Select distinct c.emp_card_no, c.emp_name, c.Dt_Of_Join from emp_mst c  
                    join emp_mon_day d 
                    on c.emp_card_no=d.emp_mkey 
                    WHERE Dt_Of_Join =  CAST(FLOOR(CAST( DATEADD(month, -6, GETDATE()) AS FLOAT ))AS DATETIME)  
            OPEN daily_Allocate   
            FETCH NEXT FROM daily_Allocate INTO
            @emp_card_no, @emp_name, @Dt_Of_Join
            WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
            BEGIN   
                    select  @Total_days = Sum(total_day),@Days_worked = Sum(days_worked)
                    from emp_mon_day a      
                    where  a.emp_mkey = @emp_card_no
                    group by emp_mkey       
                    
                        PRINT 'Employee Card no ' + cast(@emp_card_no as char)      --Working
                        PRINT 'Total days ' + cast(@Total_days as char)             --Working
                        PRINT 'Days Worked ' +  cast(@Days_worked as char)          --Working
                        
                set @Final_PaidDayLop = 0;
                declare @TotalRecord as varchar(155)
                set @TotalRecord = 0;
            
                Select @Final_PaidDayLop = sum(days)       
                    from  P_Emp_Del_App_Hdr c join P_Emp_Del_App_trl d on c.mkey=d.mkey       
                    where c.delete_flag='N' and app_flag='Y' and c.year = @actualYear
                and c.emp_mkey = @emp_card_no
                
                PRINT 'Final Paid LOP '  + cast(@Final_PaidDayLop as char)         -- Not working
    
            Select @TotalRecord =  ((1.75 * 6) / @Total_days) * (@Days_worked + @Final_PaidDayLop) 
                from emp_mon_day a where  a.emp_mkey = @emp_card_no group by emp_mkey   
    
            PRINT 'Total Record ' + cast(@TotalRecord as char)                     -- Not working
            
                  FETCH NEXT FROM daily_Allocate INTO 
                  @emp_card_no, @emp_name, @Dt_Of_Join 
            END   
        CLOSE daily_Allocate   
        DEALLOCATE daily_Allocate
END
```

In that cursor, I'm testing the data by PRINTING its value, but for some print it is not working.

DETAILS are mentioned below

**NOT PRINTING LINE**

```
PRINT 'Final Paid LOP '  + cast(@Final_PaidDayLop as char)
```

AND

```
PRINT 'Total Record ' + cast(@TotalRecord as char)
```

**PRINTING LINE**

```
PRINT 'Employee Card no ' + cast(@emp_card_no as char)
                        PRINT 'Total days ' + cast(@Total_days as char)
                        PRINT 'Days Worked ' +  cast(@Days_worked as char)
```

I'm confused why some are not getting printed.

I am using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Where do you declare the working parameters?

Comment: @sagi: hi sagi, I have declared all the parameters at the top of the procedure

Comment: If you just print without a paramater, does it print?

Comment: @sagi: i got the issue why it was not getting printed, actually when I ran it statically like this `Select sum(days) FinalLOP  from  P_Emp_Del_App_Hdr c join P_Emp_Del_App_trl d on c.mkey=d.mkey       
 where c.delete_flag='N' and app_flag='Y' and c.year = 2016
 and c.emp_mkey = '2519'` the output was **NULL**, now how to handle null part because of that my **TotalRecord** was also not getting printed due to NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the select of @Final_PaidDayLop with this:

```
           Select @Final_PaidDayLop = coalesce(sum(days),0)      
                from  P_Emp_Del_App_Hdr c join P_Emp_Del_App_trl d on c.mkey=d.mkey       
                where c.delete_flag='N' and app_flag='Y' and c.year = @actualYear
            and c.emp_mkey = @emp_card_no
```

Comment: `FinalLOP` is printing as `0` but There are 9 as Total records but they are also getting printed as **0**